# How can I retain the custom string color while allowing the XAML indentation to be of the same background color?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xaml, settings, background-color

Just having reinstalled everything I wanted to get back to a dark color theme for Visual Studio 2010.

[I downloaded the .vssettings](https://nprogramming.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/visual-studio-2010-resharper-6-color-theme/#comment-61) and imported them. Everything looks fine except in XAML files where the indents gets a brown/yellowish background that is very distracting:

[image]

I checked other file types (.cs, .xml etc.) and I only see this behavior with XAML files which led me to believe I would be able to correct this by changing one of the "XAML" prefixed settings under `Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors`.

But I cannot find anything that matches what I see.

The setting seems to be governed by the "string" setting in `Tools-->Options-->Environment-->Fonts`.

How can the custom string color be kept while allowing the XAML indentation to be the same color as the background?

Comment: Further investigation revealed that the effect is governed by the "string" setting in Tools-->Options-->Environment-->Fonts. I find it strange that indentation in XAML files is affected by this. Indentation in other file types remain unchanged when I modify that color setting. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: I tested tabs vs spaces and it doesn't change a thing. I am afraid that this is a bug.

Comment: This behavior doesn't happen in VS 2012, so most likely is a bug in VS 2010.

Comment: I have actually never seen it in VS2010 before. Well, no big deal really. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Any other plugin installed?

Answer (score 1):

You have probably turned on the "View White Space" option.  To turn this off via the menus you can select Edit->Advanced->View White Space.  The default keyboard shortcut for this is Ctrl E, Ctrl W.